# Would a tattoo saying in Thai "Nothing is mine, not even myself" be considered offensive?

Tags: thailand, culture, religion

I grew up in SE Asia (Singapore) and am planning to go back for a few weeks this year with my husband. While doing some travel research, I found a photo of a quote in Chiang Mai that really resonates with me:

http://www.panoramio.com/photo/106610714

I believe it is located at Wat Chedi Luang? Anyway, I would love a tattoo of this phrase in Thai.

Does anyone know if this would be in any way offensive?

I'm aware that actually images of Buddha are inappropriate, but wasn't sure about this.

Comment: Besides the excellent answer below, let me note that the translation does not exactly match: Thai text says "…not even our own bodies", and this may not be a connotation you expected. The word ตัว "body" should be used with care. It can be considered vulgar in some societies, unlike English where this very word can be used even in Biblical context. I would vote for แม้แต่ **ร่างกาย** เราเอง.

Answer (score 9):

If it's on a sign hanging in a temple, you can be pretty sure the content of the quote is not offensive, and neither is there any particular taboo about tattooing yourself with Thai characters.

That said, [visible tattoos](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5511/visible-tattoos-as-esl-teacher-in-thailand) on women are quite literally considered "tramp stamps" in Thailand, they're virtually unknown outside prostitution.  And it's just [generally a bad idea](http://hanzismatter.blogspot.com.au/) to get tattooed in a language you (& your tattooist) don't read & write fluently, all it takes is a small typo to turn it into gibberish or worse.

Comment: I think that it is especially true if you want to get the tattoo in Singapore, not sure how easy it is to find a tattooist who knows Thai.

Comment: There are a few tattoo parlours in Golden Mile Complex.  No prizes for guessing what group comprises the largest section of the shopping mall's clientele.

Comment: In that case, it might just be easiest to ask one of them, hoping that they are not keen on playing jokes on tourists :-P

Answer (score 4):

This phrase is safe to tattoo. And it's not offensive nor a "tramp stamp" for a foreigner as some comments stated. In Thai ตัวเราเอง [thua rao eng] means both "ourselves" and also points towards the speaker/writer, thus the meaning "myself". I'm a native speaker of Thai, and I can assure you that we're not offended by this phrase. I don't know where other people get their negative views, but they aren't native Thai opinions. Just don't tattoo it on taboo spots, which is obvious.

Comment: I'll rewrite this phrase here in case you wish to copy and paste. I recommend picking a Thai font from google fonts or letting a Thai artist help you choose a font to print out or draw: ไม่มีอะไรเป็นของเราเอง แม้แต่ตัวเราเอง